# Nginx reverse proxy losts connection to PHP container after upgrade

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm

I have two containers inside a [Rancher](https://rancher.com/) stack. One is [php-fpm](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/57b41cfc2d1e07acab2e60d59a0cb19d83056fc1/7.1/jessie/fpm/Dockerfile) container which is serving an application. The second one is Nginx acting as a reverse proxy.

The nginx has following configurations mounted:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  open_file_cache max=100;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Everything works well until the `php` container is upgraded. From that moment on the reverse proxy returns `502 Bad Gateway`. Following message is logged in the error log:

```
*5 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream,
client: 10.42.154.177, server: [hidden url],
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://10.42.241.63:9000",
host: "[hidden-url]"
```

So instead of using the hostname, nginx uses IP directly which obviously gets changed during container upgrade. **How to make this work, always?**

I could create health checks so nginx container would get recreated  however my error logs get flooded with messages.

Comment: are you sure that php-fpm configuration is the same and the service is running in php-fpm container?

Comment: Yes, like I said everything works fine until I upgrade the `php-fpm` container and it has new IP assigned. My guess is this is a matter of proper nginx configuration however I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, only the plus version has functionality to [resolve upstream's IP through a DNS server](https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/).

I ended creating blank php file called `healthcheck.php` which is used by Rancher to perform regular health checks. If the `php` container responds with non 200/300 http code nginx container gets recreated. I also can exclude that file from the access log in the nginx configuration.

That has to do I guess.